# RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage does not delete itself even though TEXT does?

Tags: c#, .net, requiredfieldvalidator

This is some old code that I am not too familiar with :

```
 RequiredFieldValidator vldRequired = new RequiredFieldValidator();
                    vldRequired.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
                    vldRequired.Text = "*";
                    vldRequired.ControlToValidate = "txtSetting";
                    vldRequired.ID = "vldRequired";
                    vldRequired.Enabled = true;
                    vldRequired.ErrorMessage = SettingTitle + " is required";
                    returnCell.Controls.Add(vldRequired);
```

Where, IF you tab passed a required field the * will show up next to it.  THE ErrorMessage only shows up when a Submit is clicked (that is all fine).

However, once you fill in the required field and tab out of the input, the "*" goes away but the ErrorMessage stays -- I cannot figure out how to make that ErrorMessage go away when the * does.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just ran into a similar issue on one of my projects. It's been a while since I've used the requiredFieldValidator. Try removing your Text Property as it interferes with the Error Message. Also ensure that you don't have a Validation Summary on the page as that may cause fixed messages to linger in front of the user even though they have corrected the the problem on the client side.

```
RequiredFieldValidator vldRequired = new RequiredFieldValidator();
                    vldRequired.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
                    //vldRequired.Text = "*";
                    vldRequired.ControlToValidate = "txtSetting";
                    vldRequired.ID = "vldRequired";
                    vldRequired.Enabled = true;
                    vldRequired.ErrorMessage = SettingTitle + " is required";
                    returnCell.Controls.Add(vldRequired);
```

Comment: Just as I suspected. I added a Validation Summary to my page and sure enough the error message would not disappear in the Validation but the RequiredFieldValidator's "*" would disappear once the error was corrected. Try removing the Validation Summary. In most cases  it's overkill.

Comment: Validation Summary, that was it.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the Text property as well. Otherwise the user will not see the actual error message. They'll only get the "*". Once the Text property is removed the error message is what will appear.